# MouseHover, MouseEnter function precedence

Tags: jquery

If i define mousehover , mouseenter and mouseleave function on same element. Say  element. Then move my cursor to the  element, then which function call first, mousehover or mouseenter?. Similarly mouseleave or hoverout function?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Hover fires before enter or leave.  This really doesn't warrant a question as you could have tested this yourself very simply.

Comment: Actually i have <a> elements. When you mousehover it, then it animate, and when mouseenter it, then i call submenu. So i just want to know which function call first, so i will do the things in that function first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mouse enter and mouse leave firing only once. mouse hover firing just before enter and just before leave.

see an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qaXGf/1/